# Facebook like button create automatically

Tags: html, facebook-like

Is it possible without going to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/ and putting in the URL, to rub a webservice or something and have it return the Iframe code? I do not want to go to that site manually. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just construct the URL yourself,

```
<iframe 
  src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2F"
  scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="height: 62px; width: 100%"
  allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

and put your site's URL urlencoded behind the `?href=`.

Comment: I tried that but the ? for my url querystring was all screwed up. Is there a way to get around that?

Comment: What does *screwed up* mean in this context?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

just modify the urls array :)

http://jsfiddle.net/Tatqu/